# If $\kappa$ is an $\eta$-extendible cardinal then it is $\delta$-extendible for every $\delta <\eta$

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I have an hint in order to prove the statement in the title:

> If $\kappa$ is an $\eta$-extendible cardinal then it is $\delta$-extendible for every $\delta <\eta$.

The hint is to prove that the elementary embedding $j:V_{\kappa+\eta}\longrightarrow V_\beta$ (which exists for some $\beta$ by hypothesis) restricts to an elementary embedding $V_{\kappa+\delta}\longrightarrow V_\beta$.

From this I can conclude, but why is the hint true?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What's an elementary immersion ? Is it an elementary embedding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
j \colon V_{\kappa + \eta} \to V_{\beta}
$$
be an elementary embedding and let $\beta ' := j(\kappa + \delta) < \beta$. I claim that
$$
j \restriction V_{\kappa + \delta} \colon V_{\kappa + \delta} \to V_{\beta'}
$$
is an elementary embedding. Why? Let $\vec{x} \in V_{\kappa + \delta}$ and let $\phi$ be a formula of set theory. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
V_{\kappa + \delta} \models \phi[\vec{x}] & \iff V_{\kappa + \eta} \models "V_{\kappa + \delta} \models \phi[\vec{x}] " \\
& \iff V_{\beta} \models " j(V_{\kappa + \delta}) \models \phi[j(\vec{x})]" \\
& \iff V_{\beta'} \models \phi[j(\vec{x})].
\end{align*}
$$
The last equivalence follows because $j(V_{\kappa + \delta}) = V_{\beta'}$ using both elementarity and the fact that $V_{\beta}$ computes $V_{\beta'}$ correctly. The last part needs a bit justification, if you don't already know this fact.

Comment: Note that it's $V_{\beta'}$ and not $V_{\beta}$ that is the range of the restricted elementary embedding. (You should also note that in fact $\mathrm{ran}(j \restriction V_{\kappa + \delta}) \subseteq V_{\beta'}$ - this may not be self-evident, depending on your prior knowledge.)